# Is objectify on Google cloud endpoints compatible with java 8?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I recently moved my cloud endpoints project to java 8 .I am using objectify as my storage .I noticed some instabilities with the fetching of data from objectify .
1) The performance is ridiculously slow .
2) The loading of data with objectify from datastore throws 
18:52:56.610
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Comment: Try increasing your instance size and see if that helps.

Comment: @saiyr. I don't see how that fits in logically.

Answer (score 1):

Startup requests happen with GAE and have nothing to do with what libraries you are using; sometimes a request comes in and there are no instances ready to serve it. Thus GAE starts a new instance and serves the request.

Objectify works great with Java8.

Comment: Please can we see a working example of using objectify with java 8 ?

Comment: I observed that the issue is with the web filter annotation for java servlet 3.1 for java 8 .I'm still looking deep .

Comment: I have reverted back to 1.7 because 1.8 doesn't work at all .I think the filter doesn't get initialized and also the servlet that loads on start up .

Comment: how do I properly Initialize objectify with annotations in java 8 with servlet 3.1 I'm thinking the problem might be coming from here

Comment: This is really a Java question - you just need to get the ObjectifyFilter installed. Not sure if there is a better way, but one option is to subclass ObjectifyFilter and put the Servlet 3.1 annotations on that.